# How does µlaw encoding work with 16-bit signals?

Tags: digital-communications

I am new to DSP, so I wan't to know a couple of things. How does µlaw encoding function on a log scale such that you can input 16-bit signals and get the 8-bit µlaw signal output, after compression, and then use that as a building block to expand it back to 16-bit signals. I would love if someone can guide me through this. Also, how is this lossless compression, if that is what it is.

Comment: It can be implemented with lookup tables in both directions. It is not lossless.

Comment: That doesn't help much, sorry.

Comment: Are basically asking how $\mu$-law works?

Comment: Yes Phonon, you got me.

Comment: When you look up $\mu$-law companding on the web, such as [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9C-law_algorithm), what part don't you understand?  It seems pretty clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%CE%9C-law_algorithm&oldid=1061227909):

The forward transformation is:
$$F(x) = \newcommand{\sgn}{\operatorname{sgn}} \sgn(x)\frac{\ln(1+\mu |x|)}{\ln(1+\mu)}$$

Where $F(x)$ and $x$ both lie between -1 and 1.

After this conversion is it necessary to quantize $F(x)$ appropriately.

The reverse transformation is given by:
$$F^{-1}(y) = \sgn(y)\frac{(1+\mu)^{|y|}-1}{\mu}$$

Where typically $\mu = 255$.

This is not a lossless encoding due to the quantization steps.

Due to the typically small range of the data type used in this encoding the forward and reverse transformations can be easily implemented as a lookup table.